# Workflow 4.0 Argument Errors

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm having two errors with workflow, one I think is caused by a bug in the compling with VS2010, its

Error   1   Could not resolve attachable member {clr-namespace:;}Flowchart1.requestType C:\Documents and Settings\Hilliard\my documents\visual studio 10\Projects\WorkflowConsoleApplication1\WorkflowConsoleApplication1\Flowchart1.xaml   WorkflowConsoleApplication1

That error usually goes away after two builds in a row. I don't know if its related but another error gets thrown once the workflow runs in the Partial Class in the new

"Cannot set unknown Member 'requestType'. Line:3 Offset:4".

Anyone have any clue if I'm doing something wrong here? I just want to pass in two parameters into my workflow and use them throughout the workflow. Right now the workflow won't even load as them defiend in the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell this information from your description, I think you really need to add more details:
-how are you declaring requestType?
-how are you passing the arguments in to your workflow?
-what is the XAML you are getting the compile error from?

You could also try asking your question on the MS forum for WF 4.0 Beta1... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/threads

Comment: Tim I have actually submitted an issue to Microsoft through the Connect site. I noticed it being an issue with default values on the arguments for the workflow. If you had no default values it was fine, if you had default values for the arguments it broke. I included my XAML with the Microsoft Connect issue. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

by that "{clr-namespace:;}" you have in your error message, i suspect you're refering to some class within your current assembly (say a custom activity or a type from within your compiling assembly).

if that's the case, then simply go ahead with splitting your assembly, and moving your custom activities and/or types (which are referenced by your workflow instance) into the new one.